# Is the "B" in Brussels Sprouts capitalized? What about the F(s) in French Fries?

Tags: etymology, grammaticality, orthography, capitalization

Is the "B" in Brussels Sprouts capitalized?

What about the "F" or "F's" of French Fries?

I suppose it's not standard to capitalize "F" in french fries... In that case what is the proper way to write it? Please cite sources.

Comment: *I* don't! I love brussels sprouts. The NYT doesn't either: *"For delicious brussels sprouts, cook them in very hot oil."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of a faulty presupposition.

Comment: What you mean, "We," Kemo Sabe?

Comment: Hmm... I write "french fries", and I see it that way all the time. Do you capitalize it, @medica? I don't think brussels sprouts needs to be capitalized, and the dictionaries seem torn on the matter. m-w.com lists it lower case. I only capitalize the sprouts when my electronic devices' auto-correct does it for me.

Comment: I did a [Googe Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brussels+sprout%2CBrussels+sprout&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrussels%20sprout%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBrussels%20sprout%3B%2Cc0) analysis that suggests `brussels sprouts` constitutes a substantial fraction of the references, and some of the `Brussels sprouts` references are probably at the start of sentences. I'd say the lower case is an acceptable spelling, but that's mostly opinion. (And the _majority_ of the `french fries` references used the lower-case `f`.)

Comment: I'm sure we've covered this before. These things are genericisations (or equivalent); the original reference used the proper noun / adjective as considered appropriate, but the tendency for compounds is for them to drop the capitalisation over time, as the modifier gets more distant in sense from the original implication. I've not seen 'german measles' yet. One should check in an up-to-date dictionary on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: If you want to follow the trend in making your choice of case, I can see a real problem you may encounter: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=French+beans%2Cfrench+beans%2CFrench+fries%2Cfrench+fries&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFrench%20beans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrench%20beans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFrench%20fries%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrench%20fries%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: related: [When should types of cheese be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188491/when-should-types-of-cheese-be-capitalized).

Comment: @Medica Perhaps I should just change the title phrasing to get rid of the presupposition. Essentially the question is about usage.

Comment: Although I would like to point out that I don't think everyone here capitalizes "Brussels"

Comment: I say you can capitalize it any way you want.  Just don't make me eat them (or even smell them)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Grammarphobia Blog](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/11/food-names.html):

> **How to capitalize food names**
>
> **Q**: I’m never sure about how food names are capitalized. Is it “Waldorf
>   salad” or “waldorf salad”? “Swiss cheese” or “swiss cheese”? “French
>   fries” or “french fries”? And so on.
>
> **A**: The one thing we can tell you for sure is that the generic noun in
>   these dishes—the “salad,” the “fries,” and so on—is lowercased.
>
> But should the other part of the name be capitalized if it’s derived
>   from a proper name, like “Waldorf” or “French” or “Caesar”? On that
>   point, dictionaries and usage guides disagree. In some cases, their
>   policies have more holes than swiss cheese.
>
> We’ll start with the argument against capitals, which can be found in
>   The ***Chicago Manual of Style* (16th ed.)**:
>
> “Personal, national, or geographical names, and words derived from
>   such names, are often lowercased when used with a *nonliteral* meaning.”
>   Note that the manual emphasizes the word “nonliteral.”
>
> For example, the editors write, “the cheese known as ‘gruyère’ takes
>   its name from a district in Switzerland but is not necessarily from
>   there; ‘swiss cheese’ (lowercase s) is a cheese that resembles Swiss
>   emmentaler” but doesn’t come from Switzerland.
>
> Thus the manual’s list of terms derived from proper names includes
>   these lowercase examples: “brie,” “brussels sprouts,” “cheddar,”
>   “dutch oven,” “frankfurter,” “french dressing,” “french fries,”
>   “scotch whisky,”* “stilton,” and “swiss cheese” (not made in
>   Switzerland).
>
> The *Chicago Manual* doesn’t specifically mention the salads named for
>   the Waldorf-Astoria Hotel and the chef Caesar Cardini. We assume from
>   its guidelines that Chicago would recommend “waldorf salad” and
>   “caesar salad.”
>
> The style guide acknowledges that while it prefers to lowercase proper
>   names “in their nonliteral use,” some such names “are capitalized in
>   *Webster’s*.”
>
> Sure enough, ***Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary* (11th ed.)**,
>   like the online *Merriam-Webster Unabridged*, has entries for both
>   “Waldorf salad” and “Caesar salad.”
>
> *M-W Collegiate* doesn’t seem as consistent here as the *Chicago 
>   Manual*. For example, the dictionary lowercases “napoleon” (the pastry
>   gets its name from Naples, not from the emperor).
>
> It also lowercases “crêpes suzette” (named after a real Suzette), as
>   well as “brussels sprouts” and “french fries,” but notes that in these
>   cases the parts derived from proper names are “often cap.”
>
> And in one rather baffling entry, the *M-W Unabridged* has “Baked
>   Alaska,” with “baked Alaska” given as a lesser alternative. (Why the
>   folks at *M-W* would prefer to capitalize “baked” is beyond us.)
>
> The ***American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* (5th 
>   ed.)** leaves us scratching our heads, too. It capitalizes the first
>   term in “Brussels sprouts” and “French toast,” but lowercases “french
>   fries” and “caesar salad.”
>
> Our former employer, the **New York Times**, recommends in its style guide
>   that “crêpes suzette,” “napoleon” (the pastry), “brussels sprouts,”
>   and “baked alaska” be lowercased. But it capitalizes the first word in
>   “Bavarian cream” and always capitalizes “French” in food names
>   (“French fries,” “French dressing,” “French toast,” etc.).
>
> The conclusion? If you want to be consistent, pick one route or the
>   other: (1) Always capitalize food terms derived from proper names, or
>   (2) lowercase them when there’s no longer a literal connection.
>
> In the end, there’s no right or wrong here. This is a stylistic issue,
>   and if lexicographers can’t agree, the rest of us shouldn’t lose sleep
>   over it. *Bon appétit*. >> Patricia T. O’Conner and Stewart Kellerman

- It may be that CMOS is breaking some law here. The [Scotch Whisky Association](http://www.scotch-whisky.org.uk/media/43293/swacentenaryhistoryfinalforweb.pdf) has:

> As a result, no court in any country has ever ruled that ‘Scotch
>   Whisky’ is generic. In total, the SWA Council has authorised legal
>   action against over 1,000 brands and nearly 3,000 trademarks worldwide
>   have been opposed.

One remembers the court case threatened and perhaps brought against people dropping the capitalisation of the word 'Biro'.

Comment: +1 This is a useful discussion, but I wonder whether the authors can seriously think that, if you choose the alternative of always capitalizing food terms derived from proper names, you should adopt the spelling _butterScotch_.

Comment: Perhaps on alternate days: _butterscotch_: [C19: perhaps first made in Scotland, or perhaps from scotch1 (sense 3), 'to cut or score', because it was originally cut with a knife into small pieces] [Collins]