# French fries or french fries?

Tags: capitalization, style-manuals

Yesterday I came across the following sentence, using "french" fries in lowercase, in an exercise book for non-native speakers of English:

We ordered two "french" fries and two apple pies.

So I have googled "(f)rench fries" in lowercase. To my surprise, l have found out that both styles are used, lowercase and uppercase. My question is: which style is more appropriate in formal writing?

Comment: The older question was closed, propbably, for lack of research, but it has the answer you're looking for: [**Is the “B” in Brussels Sprouts capitalized?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238034/is-the-b-in-brussels-sprouts-capitalized)

Comment: Also related: [When should types of cheese be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188491/when-should-types-of-cheese-be-capitalized)

Comment: In *formal* writing, I would really choose lowercase, I believe that anglophones no longer consider *french fries* to be French, they just describe a type of fried chip. Whereas *Italian wine* and *Chinese takeaway* tells you the origin of the product,   (although a Chinese takeaway can be found in any part of the world)  I would in any case capitalise the first word (adjective).

Comment: Thanks Mari. I didn' know that this question has been raised before.

Comment: The problem of capitalization often rears its head when the noun is the actual name of a company, e.g. *biro*, and *kleenex* to name but two.

Comment: I would always capitalise the "F" in French fries. Examples of it with lower case are just sloppy. Same with "Swiss roll", "Belgian waffles" and so on. To advise students to use lower case would be wrong since some examiners would down-mark it. Don't risk it!

Comment: @BillJ *sloppy*? That's just your personal opinion, isn't it? Care to prove that statement? Do you always capitalise the words Biro, Hoover, Google, and the Internet? I do for the latter two but I don't sneer at anyone who doesn't. Once upon a time *email* was written *e-mail* that became obsolete pretty quickly. I see *gorgonzola cheese* in lowercase, never crossed my mind to say that the producer or the maker was *sloppy*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Touched a nerve, have I?

Comment: @BillJ no. I found your statement annoying and supercilious. Look at the question and its answer which I linked above.

Comment: @Mari-LouA French mustard, English mustard Brussels Sprouts and so on.

Comment: @Mari-LouA And I find yours rude and bombastic, so pipe down.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I and others will down-mark anyone who uses lower case. Take that on board.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56526/discussion-between-billj-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: @Peter Shor I had a capital sandwich the other day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the lowercase spelling has the upperhand (*ho, ho, ho*)

[image]

But according to Google books [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=french%20fries%2CFrench%20fries&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrench%20fries%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFrench%20fries%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfrench%20fries%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2CFrench%20fries%3B%2Cc1), the Brits use either indistinctively.

[image]

However, Ngram is not really indicative of spelling preferences because many of the results are from book titles, where it is conventional to capitalise nearly every word. e.g *More Than Just French Fries*, *Who Ate My French Fries?*, and *French Fries: The Ultimate Recipe Guide* etc.

So lets take a look at *Google Scholar* and find out what they have to say

- **[French fries](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22French%20fries%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5)** throws up  44,800 results
- **[french fries](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22french%20fries%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5)** pips them at the post with  45,100 results

Again, I suspect that many of the uppercase results are tied to titles.

Conclusion? Neither is wrong, go with your personal preference.

EDIT

More references, and support. Yikes! I am about to cite [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/should-you-capitalize-the-french-in-french-fries) (a few venerable members on EL&U consider her “tips” to, erm... lack authority). Miss  Mignon Fogarty writes

> Although we often capitalize a country or city name when it’s part of a food name, that’s not always the case, and it’s typically not the case with french fries. **Most sources say to keep it lowercase.**
>
> - The reasoning given by the AP Stylebook* writers is that *french* describes the style of cut and doesn’t refer directly to the country.
> - The Chicago Manual of Style also recommends keeping *french* lowercase because *french* isn’t being used to literally refer to the country.
> - They give *swiss cheese* as another example—it’s lowercase because it’s not made in Switzerland. It’s named after a cheese called *Emmental*, which it resembles and which is made in Switzerland. It is capitalized because the name does relate directly to the Emmental region where the cheese originated.
>
> On the other hand, four out of five examples of the phrase *french fries* in the *Oxford English Dictionary* have the word *french* capitalized, and the entry in the *Merriam-Webster* online dictionary has *[french fry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/french%20fry)* lowercase, but notes that *french* is often capitalized.

Comment: Yes except that with or without a capital, 'french fries' is still used by Brits mainly on pretentious restaurateurs…

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not to capitalize "french" in this instance is a matter of style. Both the AP Stylebook and the Chicago Manual of Style do indeed recommend using lower case (not citing "Grammar Girl," but read it myself back when I had subscriptions), but McDonald's and Burger King both capitalize it in their promotional materials.

Based on my own observations, if the usage of a proper noun becomes sufficiently distant in meaning from the proper noun itself, the capital tends to drop off. Whether it has become sufficiently distant or not is a matter of opinion, of course, so there will generally be variations.

Some cursory nGram research (allowing titles and beginnings of sentences to skew the results) suggests that *herculean task* and *Herculean task* are about equally common over time, fluctuating back and forth in popularity. *Swiss cheese* is more common than *swiss cheese*, but the latter is fairly common. And *body english* began showing up around 1940. The lowercase was more common for a few years, and quickly fell out of favor as the term became increasingly popular; *body english* is still used, but at present it's only a fraction as popular as *body English*.

Comment: It would be wonderful to see excerpts from the references you cite.

Comment: What corpora/software did you use to get the results you mention in paragraph 3?

Comment: @Laurel1 I just used [google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams). You can enter things like "Herculean, herculean" and get a graph. You can then look at examples in google books. Mari-Lou A's answer uses it.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 Yes, I would like to do that, too, but I don't have subscriptions to the AP and Chicago stylebooks at present, and if I did, I would have to agree not to quote them directly here AFAIK. If you follow the link in Mari-Lou A's answer, you'll see the links to the style manuals in the GrammarGirl article, if you should wish to take out a subscription in either or both.