# Do you capitalize "Cajun" if referring to cooking?

Tags: capitalization

Is 'Cajun' when used as a premodifier for 'cooking' always capitalized? Why or why not?

Comment: Your title and question body don't seem to match.

Comment: Closely related: [When should types of cheese be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188491/when-should-types-of-cheese-be-capitalized) (see EA's answer).

Comment: Though genericisation and/or the/an associated loss of capitalisation (eg Hoover ---> hoover; french fries; frankfurter; sandwich; shrapnel ...) is far from uncommon, from the examples I've found on the internet, it seems to be happening here extremely slowly, if at all.

Comment: I generally see it capitalized.  And Ngram can hardly find any instanced that aren't capitalized: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+cajun+cuisine%2Cand+Cajun+cuisine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20Cajun%20cuisine%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @James Webster Unless you can find something far more authoritative than "I can't find many/any valid occurrences of _cajun_ rather than _Cajun_", I wouldn't bother answering. The general question of proper nouns/adjectives dropping capitals was addressed at the 'When should types of cheese be capitalized?' thread; the behaviour of individual examples seems illogical and unpredictable.

Comment: I have never seen *anything* Cajun spelled with a lower case C.  The thought makes me shudder.

Answer (score 1):

I just consulted five dictionaries.  They all think "Cajun" should be capitalized, even when it refers to cooking, culture, etc.  That should do it!

I'd say it's capitalized because it's still a proper name -- though as Ashworth points out above, associations of words drift.  The only way to be sure is to consult the dictionary.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to consult current usage.

Comment: Yes, that is what reference works on current usage of words are called.

Comment: But a (real) dictionary isn't "current".

Comment: Try Merriam-Webster.  Or if you have a better way to definitively answer OP's question -- post your answer!  I am sure he will be delighted to see it.

Comment: Dictionaries are never going to be as current as current usage. Dictionaries don't drive language. They document it.

Comment: Exactly:  dictionaries document language.  The best answers at EL&U are things that are documented, not merely our own opinions.  Propose an alternative method for knowing current usage -- something more accurate than "some guy's opinion on Internet" -- and we'll jump at it.